# UIDatePicker crashing

Tags: swift, uipickerview, uidatepicker

In my `UIViewController` I have a 2 `UITextFields` A and B. 
A has its `inputView` set to a `UIDatePicker` programmatically.
B has its `inputView` set to a `UIPickerView` programmatically, the `dataSource` and `delegate` of which I have defined.

When a value in A's picker is changed, I have a selector attached to it which updates the text in A.
When a value in B's picker is changed, I send a `NSNotification` from its `dataSource, delegate` class to the `UIViewController`. TextField B basically allows the user to add n **number of years** to the date in A. Note that at this point the B's picker is still visible.

So far so good.

Now when I receive the `NSNotification` in my `UIViewController`, my `notificationReceived` selector method gets the input from B, does some calculations, and updates the picker and the text in A. The relevant parts of the code are shown below:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var textFieldA: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var textFieldB: UITextField!
    let datePickerA = UIDatePicker()
    let pickerB     = UIPickerView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // init A
        datePickerA.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.DateAndTime
        picker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(datePickerAChanged(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
        textFieldA.inputView = datePickerA

        // init B
        pickerB.dataSource   = bDataSource //bDataSource is the datasource and delegate class instance
        pickerB.delegate     = bDataSource
        textFieldB.inputView = pickerB

    }

    func notificationReceived(notification: NSNotification) {
        switch notification.name {
        case foo:
            // do calculations and get the updated date
            let nsdate = calculateNewDate()
            self.datePickerA.setDate(nsdate, animated: false)
            self.textFieldA.text = newDateString()
        default:
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

This arrangement works fine when I first highlight B, select a value, and then highlight A. But when I highlight A first, then highlight B and select a value in B, and then tap on A again, then my application crashes with error:

> My App [] * Assertion failure in -[UIPickerTableView
>   _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:willDisplay:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3512.60.7/UITableView.m:10594 
>   My App [] * Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView dataSource is
>   not set'

If I comment out `self.datePickerA.setDate(nsdate, animated: false)` then it doesn't crash. I check the nsdate so that it is not nil or invalid so thats not the problem.

There are no variables going out of scope here, and I am at my wits end trying to understand why this is crashing. Help!

**Update:** I have uploaded the project files here: https://github.com/urbanmachinist/DatePickerCrash/tree/master
The **readme** shows steps to reproduce the error.

Comment: So what exactly is the date of that `NSDate` which had it crashed?

Comment: No specific date. Any value I select in picker B (eg. 1, which would add 1 years to todays date which is in A). If I had not highlighted and brought up datepicker A, and I make a selection in B and then tap A, then it works fine. But once A is highlighted and I make a change in B and go back, then it crashes.

Comment: Do you have an exception breakpoint set?  What line of your code is it crashing on?  It would be good to see more of your code related to the setup of your pickers.

Comment: Thats the problem, its not crashing on a particular line that I wrote as such. When I comment out the `setDate()` on pickerA (shown above), then the crash doesn't happen. Since pickerA is a class variable, its not going out of scope or anything here.

Comment: I will create a small github project which shows this crash in a few mins.

Comment: I know it's not a specific date (that's why we need a picker here). But that exact date you feed into the `setDate()` might be the issue, as you don't know what caused the crash, you shouldn't rule out anything.

Comment: Well, one example date is **2017-05-07 21:15:58 +0000**. This is when the user selects '1' in the custom picker, which adds 1 to todays date. I printed this before feeding it to `setDate()`

Comment: I think what @Bek ment was you should set a breakpoint before `setDate()`, then go step by step and see exactly where the exception happened. Comment out that line and it didn't crash does not necessarily mean it's the cause. We have no idea what e.g. `newDateString()` was doing and what goes on after that.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that. But as the log says, the crash happens in the `setDate()` method internally when it tries to update the picker: `UIPickerTableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:willDisplay:`. Cannot debug that.. I am creating a small project which shows this which I will put up on Github in about half an hour :)

Comment: @Zhi-WeiCai, Bek, I have added a fully functioning project on git (only 2 files - viewcontroller and picker-source) which shows this issue. Link is above in my question at the end!

Comment: Well that's not a project but files.

Comment: Sorry, having some issue with my got setup in Xcode so had to upload files manually. But that is all the code in the project along with the storyboard.

Comment: I have created only one UIDatePicker() but was using twice then i received the same crash , but when i allocated twice as per use then didn't get crash.